# How to judge which language a input belongs to in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to add a item in Services on macOS such as:

I pick a word on webpage, then search its explain on Wikipedia.

If the word is english, i want to search "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", if the word is chinese, i want to search "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/". so firstly I need to judge the language of input. I want to how to do it in AppleScript. Thanks.

Comment: show your approach. Thanks.

Comment: `on run {input, parameters}
 open location "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & input
 return input
end run`

Comment: You can't.  You need to use AppleScriptObjC.

Comment: Sad, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

Determining the language of a piece of text can't be done in vanilla AppleScript as far as I know, but it can be done using AppleScriptObjC.

Although you weren't that keen on this revelation, nonetheless, I'm including a snippet that demonstrates it's actually pretty easy to do what you want:

```
    to guessLanguage for input
        script
            use framework "Foundation"
            property this : a reference to current application
            property NSLTag : a reference to NSLinguisticTagger of this

            to guessLanguage()
                (NSLTag's dominantLanguageForString:input) as text
            end guessLanguage
        end script

        result's guessLanguage()
    end guessLanguage
```

You should place this handler at the bottom of your script, after `end run`.  It can be called from anywhere within your script like so:

```
    on run {input, parameters}
        set [input] to the input
        guessLanguage for the input
        set lang to text 1 thru 2 of result

        open location "https://" & lang & ".wikipedia.org/wiki/" & input
    end run

    to guessLanguage for input
        .
        .
        .
    end guessLanguage
```

Here are a couple of test runs on different linguistic samples, showing the returned result next to each of them:

```
    guessLanguage for "Hello, how are you?" --> "en"
    guessLanguage for "Guten Tag, wie gehts?" --> "de"
    guessLanguage for "Salut, ça va?" --> "fr" 
    guessLanguage for "你好！你好嗎？" --> "zh-Hant"
    guessLanguage for "こんにちは、元気ですか？" --> "ja"
```

Comment: on Ventura this returns `un` for text in any language

Comment: @ccpizza I'd be very surprised if it didn't.  If you read the documentation for [`NSLinguisticTagger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger?language=objc), you can see Apple deprecated this class after macOS 11.